# Forcing an index spool

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, execution-plan, index-spool

I know its something that should be avoided for performance reasons, but am trying to show a condition where it appears as a demo on how to make sure it does not appear.

However, I end up with a missing index warning, yet the optimizer chooses not to create a temporary index.

The query I am using is

```
SELECT 
    z.a
FROM dbo.t5 AS z WITH(INDEX(0))
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT y.a 
        FROM dbo.t4 AS y
        WHERE y.a = z.a
    )
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Table schemas are:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t4
(
    a   integer NULL,
    b   varchar(1000) NULL,
    p   varchar(100) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.t5
(
    a   integer NULL,
    b   varchar(1000) NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX c1 
ON dbo.t5 (a);
```

Both tables have 10,000 rows, which you can simulate with:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.t4 
WITH 
    ROWCOUNT = 10000, 
    PAGECOUNT = 1000;

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.t5 
WITH 
    ROWCOUNT = 10000,
    PAGECOUNT = 1000;
```

The query plan is:

[image: default plan]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.2218.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="5532.16" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.407384" StatementText="select a from t5  z WITH(INDEX(0))  where exists (select a from t4 where a=z.a )" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x1B882FCEA34AEAF4" QueryPlanHash="0x1B276DC04B718F7C" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="2912" CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="10" CompileCPU="10" CompileMemory="296">
            <MissingIndexes>
              <MissingIndexGroup Impact="82.4536">
                <MissingIndex Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]">
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
                    <Column Name="[a]" ColumnId="1" />
                  </ColumnGroup>
                </MissingIndex>
              </MissingIndexGroup>
            </MissingIndexes>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="1024" SerialDesiredMemory="2912" RequiredMemory="1024" DesiredMemory="2912" RequestedMemory="2912" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="2912" MaxUsedMemory="896" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="104846" EstimatedPagesCached="11834" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.228447" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="5532.16" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.407384">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Alias="[z]" Column="a" />
              </OutputList>
              <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10000" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Hash>
                <DefinedValues />
                <HashKeysBuild>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Alias="[z]" Column="a" />
                </HashKeysBuild>
                <HashKeysProbe>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]" Column="a" />
                </HashKeysProbe>
                <ProbeResidual>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[planoper].[dbo].[t4].[a]=[planoper].[dbo].[t5].[a] as [z].[a]">
                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]" Column="a" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Alias="[z]" Column="a" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </ProbeResidual>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0110785" EstimateIO="0.0565368" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="10000" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0676153" TableCardinality="10000">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Alias="[z]" Column="a" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10000" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="true" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Alias="[z]" Column="a" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t5]" Index="[c1]" Alias="[z]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.011157" EstimateIO="0.100162" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="10000" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.111319" TableCardinality="10000">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]" Column="a" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10000" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]" Column="a" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[planoper]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[t4]" IndexKind="Heap" />
                  </TableScan>
                </RelOp>
              </Hash>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

It even tells me to create this index:

```
USE [planoper];
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[t4] ([a]);
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/operator-of-the-week---index-spool/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way to get an index spool to appear naturally is to express the requirement using slightly different syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    z.a
FROM dbo.t5 AS z
JOIN dbo.t4 AS y ON
    y.a >= z.a AND y.a <= z.a
OPTION (LOOP JOIN, MAXDOP 1, FORCE ORDER);
```

This produces an execution plan like:

[image: Join inequality plan]

[Rewriting the equality as a pair of equivalent inequalities](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/12/heaps-of-trouble.html) encourages the use of an index spool, though the spooled predicate is not exactly what you were after, the semantics are ultimately the same.

Another way is to abuse `TOP`:

```
SELECT 
    z.a
FROM dbo.t5 AS z
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT TOP ((SELECT 100)) PERCENT y.a 
        FROM dbo.t4 AS y
        WHERE y.a = z.a
    );
```

[image: top 100 percent plan]

There is no easy way to introduce the desired index spool using the original syntax; however, that's not to say it is impossible.  Since you only need this for a demo, and will ***not be using this anywhere near a production system***, I will show you another way:

```
SELECT 
    z.a
FROM dbo.t5 AS z WITH(INDEX(0))
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT y.a 
        FROM dbo.t4 AS y
        WHERE y.a = z.a
    )
OPTION (MAXDOP 1, LOOP JOIN, QUERYTRACEON 9114);
```

The execution plan is:

[image: Trace flag plan]

The index spool predicate is as desired:

```
Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [dbo].[t4].a = [dbo].[t5].[a] as [z].[a]
```

You will not be able to use this plan in a `USE PLAN` hint because the optimizer would not normally consider it.

Further reading:

- [Nested Loops Joins and Performance Spools](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/09/sql-performance/nested-loops-joins-performance-spools)
- [CROSS APPLY produces outer join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/239865/1192)